# Test your site locally with Apache on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I have various websites in my */home/user/projects* folder and I want to be able to test them on the browser with **Apache2** (they have PHP files and connect to databases).

I don't want to copy them to *var/www* each time I change something. I just want to open an URL in the browser and Apache should do the rest. Would also be great to assign fake domains by editing the hosts file but I don't know how to achieve it. I tried this [solution](http://www.elxis.org/guides/developers-guides/local-apache-and-virtual-hosts.html) but I can't access the files.

**UPDATE**
This is what I did up to now:

1. Firstly, I configure the hosts file.  I open the *etc/hosts* file with `sudo` and add the following line: `127.0.0.2    projects`. Now I am supposed to be able to access `http://projects` from the browser
2. Secondly, the Apache Virtual Directory. Inside the etc/apache2/sites-available folder I create a new file called projects and add the following code (inside */home/user/projects* I have an *index.html* file):

   `<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName com
       DocumentRoot /home/user/projects
   </VirtualHost>`

   I saved and executed `sudo a2ensite projects`, to activate the host. The symbolic links have been created in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
3. Testing, after restarting Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`. I only get this warning twice:

   `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName`

   Now I enter `http://projects` in my browser but a **403 Forbidden error** is displayed (`You don't have permission to access / on this server`). I changed permissions of the /home/user/projects with `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/projects`, it is executable yet the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the warning you should just add `ServerName` in your global configuration file.

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80> 
    ServerName com 
    DocumentRoot /home/user/projects 
</VirtualHost>`

For the error you should changer the owner of your website folder like this: `chown user_apache.group_apache /home/user/projects  -R` (for example in ubuntu/debian `chown www-data.www-data /home/user/projects  -R`)